# Best way to create admin panel in Node.JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, admin, activeadmin

I had been working with Rails and used to use [Active Admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) to create admin panel (CRUD operations and etc)

Now I'm looking for similar package for Node.JS

Is there way to do the same as Active Admin in Node?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The best I know of are listed on [our wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Alternatives). admin-on-rest has been rewritten as react-admin already.  Additional notes and comparison articles welcome.  Alternately some are [using AcitveAdmin alongside React](https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b)